# making bootable windows 10 usb / booting it

Tags: windows, ubuntu

apologies in advance in case someone answers this already (but looks like have tried everything)

Just build my first pc recently:
AMD® Ryzen 5 3600 6-core processor
ASUS Prime X570-P ATX Motherboard

burn Ubuntu to USB from my MacBook and it's all working fine. ( Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS )

The problem is that I wanna install Windows 10 into PC also.
Have done partition on SSD (have just one SSD + HDD).
But no matter what I try can't seems to install everything right.
It's one of these:

- Or pc just can't find my flash drive ( probably something is wrong with the way I burn iso to it)
- Or if it does found it I get an error somewhere in the middle of installing, that there is no file for the next step or something like that. ( iso downloaded from Microsoft official page)

I have tried it with various programs (on ios and ubuntu) or even a command line. Even changing settings in BIOS to boot any external drive.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to format your Ubuntu partition and install Windows first. Then the Ubuntu installer will automatically detect Windows and and you should be fine.
The hard way is to keep Ubuntu and install Windows. Then you will need to restore grub (Ubuntu's boot loader).

You have to run and install both OS with in (U)EFI mode and adjust some settings in UEFI. This could be the reason for the flashdrive not being found. If you have used tools like Rufus for creation of the bootable USB drive it could also be broken. It is enough to format the flashdrive with FAT32 and copy the contents of the ISO into its root.

Maybe [this](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) and [this](https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/) will help